# sparkr databricks error: too many open devices

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparkr, databricks

I was using simple data manipulation using `sparkr` on Databricks. The code was working just fine a minute ago and suddenly I started getting the following error:

> Error in png(fileName, width = plotWidth, height = plotHeight, pointsize = plotPointSize,  :  too many open devices

This happens even if I use, for example:

```
mtcars %>% select(mpg)
```

I was not making any plots. What could the solution be?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe this can be done without restarting the cluster. Just Clear State and Results and Run them all again and you will be good to go.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Thank you. `Clear States` was enough for me, I did not need to `Clear Results`, too.

Answer (score 3):

I am experiencing the same problem. The only solution seems to be to restart the cluster you're working on.

Comment: Yeah, I did the same and it started working!! Thanks!